# jQuery .val() returns null "eventually" in Chrome only

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

UPDATE 2012/07/17:
It's not just the "current_width" and "current_height" fields that get cleared - it's the entire form. Visually, the form in the browser still contains values, however jQuery "chokes", or something - and suddenly starts reading all fields in the form as null.

It's not an issue with just .val(), because I've verified it by using .children() and .each() in the preview() function:

```
var debugstring = '';
var debugform = $('#hidden_thumb_fields').children("input").each(function (){
    var child = $(this);
    debugstring += child.attr('id')+':'+child.val()+',';
});

console.log(debugstring);
```

As before, it works fine as you being to drag the selection area around, but soon afterwards it starts returning null.

Reminder that this only happens in Chrome.

---

ORIGINAL POST:
(edit: removed the mlx log output)

Scenario:

1. Uploaded image width & height are written into 2 form fields: current_width and current_height
2. imgAreaSelect enabled on the uploaded image
3. imgAreaSelect's onInit and onSelectChange call function "preview"
4. "preview" reads the values of the width and height form fields using .val()
5. As you move the selection area around, "preview" is called repeatedly
6. Eventually, .val() starts returning NULL, even though the fields still visibly contain the correct values and have not been modified.  This only happens in Chrome.  Both Firefox and Safari work pleasantly.  IE has not been tested.
7. If I use plain Javascript (document.getElementById().value), there is no problem whatsoever.

As is often cited, I am calling imgAreaSelect after $(document).ready.  The only thing done before is the setting of 3 vars, which I've included in the preview sample below.

On a side note, if there is a better or more acceptable way of getting the image width and height data, I'm all ears. The image upload script (PHP) is what sets these fields in the first place, and with my level of experience I'm not sure if there's a better way to do it. I want the real dimensions of the image, not the .css width and height, as they can be (and in my scenario, typically are) different.

The specific bit of code where the problem seems to originate is right at the beginning of the preview function:

```
function preview(img, selection) { 
    var current_width = $('#thumbnail_form').find('#current_width').val();
    var current_height = $('#thumbnail_form').find('#current_height').val();
```

Here is preview().  If I remove .find() and just go directly with $('#current_width').val(), the problem persists:

```
var thumb_width=128;
var thumb_height=128;
var counter=1;

function preview(img, selection) { 
    var current_width = $('#thumbnail_form').find('#current_width').val();
    var current_height = $('#thumbnail_form').find('#current_height').val();

    //var current_width = document.getElementById("current_width").value;
    //var current_height = document.getElementById("current_height").value;

    var scaleX = thumb_width / selection.width; 
    var scaleY = thumb_height / selection.height; 

    var img_css_width = Math.round(scaleX * current_width) + 'px';
    var img_css_height = Math.round(scaleY * current_height) + 'px';
    var img_css_margin_left = '-' + Math.round(scaleX * selection.x1) + 'px';
    var img_css_margin_top = '-' + Math.round(scaleY * selection.y1) + 'px';

    // mlx and the css fields are just to help diagnose the problem
    var mlx = document.getElementById('mlx').value;
    if (!current_width) {
        current_width = 'NULL';
    }
    if (!current_height) {
        current_height = 'NULL';
    }
    $('#mlx').val(mlx+counter+")w:"+current_width+",h:"+current_height+"\n");
    $('#img_css_width').val(img_css_width);
    $('#img_css_height').val(img_css_height);
    $('#img_css_margin_left').val(img_css_margin_left);
    $('#img_css_margin_top').val(img_css_margin_top);

    $('#displayed_icon_container').find('#displayed_icon').css({
    //$('#displayed_icon').css({
        width:  img_css_width,
        height: img_css_height,
        marginLeft: img_css_margin_left,
        marginTop: img_css_margin_top 
    });
    $('#x1').val(selection.x1);
    $('#y1').val(selection.y1);
    $('#x2').val(selection.x2);
    $('#y2').val(selection.y2);
    $('#w').val(selection.width);
    $('#h').val(selection.height);

    // if I re-write these values back to the form, I can circumvent the issue, but why is this necessary?      
    //$('#current_width').val(current_width);
    //$('#current_height').val(current_height);
    $('#sx').val(scaleX);
    $('#sy').val(scaleY);
    counter++;
}
```

Here's the relevant fields of the HTML. I don't believe the rest of the file is relevant, but am happy to post more if requested.

```
<div id='thumbnail_form'>
<form name='form' action='' method='post'>
<div id='hidden_thumb_fields'>
x1: <input type='text' name='x1' value='' id='x1' /><br />
y1: <input type='text' name='y1' value='' id='y1' /><br />
x2: <input type='text' name='x2' value='' id='x2' /><br />
y2: <input type='text' name='y2' value='' id='y2' /><br />
Selection Width (w): <input type='text' name='w' value='' id='w' /><br />
Selection Height (h): <input type='text' name='h' value='' id='h' /><br />

Old Icon Display URL: <input type='text' name='old_icon_display_URL' value='/whatever/thing.png' id='old_icon_display_URL' /><br />

Large File Width (current_width): <input type='text' name='current_width' value='' id='current_width' /><br />
Large File Height (current_height): <input type='text' name='current_height' value='' id='current_height' /><br />
Img Display Width: <input type='text' name='img_width' value='' id='img_width' /><br />
Img Display Height: <input type='text' name='img_height' value='' id='img_height' /><br />

Img CSS Width: <input type='text' name='img_css_width' value='' id='img_css_width' /><br />
Img CSS Height: <input type='text' name='img_css_height' value='' id='img_css_height' /><br />
Img CSS Margin Left: <input type='text' name='img_css_margin_left' value='' id='img_css_margin_left' /><br />
Img CSS Margin Top: <input type='text' name='img_css_margin_top' value='' id='img_css_margin_top' /><br />

scalex: <input type='text' name='sx' value='' id='sx' /><br />
scaley: <input type='text' name='sy' value='' id='sy' /><br />
Math Log X: <textarea name='mlx' value='' id='mlx' cols='40' rows='10'></textarea><br />

Icon Basedir: <input type='text' name='icon_basedir' value='' id='icon_basedir' /><br />
Icon BaseURL: <input type='text' name='icon_baseURL' value='' id='icon_baseURL' /><br />
Icon Relpath: <input type='text' name='icon_relpath' value='' id='icon_relpath' /><br />
Large Filename: <input type='text' name='large_image_filename' value='' id='large_image_filename' /><br />
Thumb Filename: <input type='text' name='thumb_image_filename' value='' id='thumb_image_filename' /><br />
</div>

<input type='button' name='cancel_thumb' value='Cancel' id='cancel_thumb' />
<input type='submit' name='save_thumb' value='Crop Image' id='save_thumb' />
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: holy code dump Batman!!!

Comment: @smd2008 can you post only relevant part of the code which has problem?

Comment: It's right here at the beginning of the preview function:`function preview(img, selection) { 
    var current_width = $('#thumbnail_form').find('#current_width').val();
    var current_height = $('#thumbnail_form').find('#current_height').val();`

Comment: The reason code dumps like this are a bad idea, is because it overloads the people trying to answer with a lot of irrelevant information without the ability to fully test it.  If you widdle out everything *but* what is essential to this problem, then chances are the problem will reveal itself to you. As it is, my gut tells me you are identifying objects with Id's when they occur multiple times or aren't properly removed after use. My guess, is that the root issue doesn't lie with browser differences, that's just where you notice it

Comment: @JoeCortopassi - I don't see any ids repeated -- which IDs are repeated?

Comment: this sounds like you are reusing the preview form for multiple images, I'm wondering if each time you load the preview form you are cloning it or something. But you dumped so much code, it's super hard to follow

Comment: This line: `$('#thumbnail_form').find('#current_width')` doesn't make sense. There can be only one element with the id `current_width`, select it directly with `$("#current_width")`. The same issue happens multiple times throughout your code.

Comment: @KevinB I completely agree. This was from a tutorial on webmotion.co.uk and although I'm no pro, I found many obvious opportunities (sometimes necessities) to improve the code including what you mentioned.  I tried it that way, and the result was the same.  The reason I went back to their "find" version was just to remove all doubt - which you just did.  :)

Comment: @JoeCortopassi - preview is called many many times in very rapid succession by imgAreaSelect's onSelectChange option/event as you drag the selection box around.  There's not a lot of detail about it on this page, but here's the documentation for it if it helps:  http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/usage.html#callback-functions

Answer (score 0):

Throw console.log(current_height,current_width); right after they are set. My guess is that they are returning null, because you are checking by Id for an element that is found multiple places in the dom

Comment: I've looked for duplicate id's and haven't found any.  Thanks for the console.log suggestion - I didn't know about it.  It shows the values going NULL after 9 updates, though I'm not sure if the # of updates is important. Sometimes the #mlx list would go NULL after 40+, though it was _usually_ after 26.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, maybe I don't understand your problem so correct me if I'm wrong:

Right now the code you posted is begin called after other code allows for the "preview" selector to be moved on the screen.

When this code is called it seems to start seeing null in two fields that are filled by other javascript prior to this code being called.

Is this correct?

If so then the problem is probably in the other code that is filling those fields.  I don't see any obvious problem with this code besides the comment below which a more careful reading of your code shows is only code you put in to try to debug the problem.

---

Maybe this is causing an overflow:

```
$('#mlx').val(mlx+counter+")w:"+current_width+",h:"+current_height+"\n");
```

What happens when you change this line:

```
<textarea name='mlx' value='' id='mlx' cols='40' rows='10'></textarea><br />
```

to this:

```
<textarea name='mlx' value='' id='mlx' cols='40' rows='200'></textarea><br />
```

Because 26 * 14 is about equal to 40 * 10.

Comment: Doesn't change the result. #mlx was added later, to help me diagnose the problem.  I can take it out completely and current_width and current_height still eventually get set to 0 after moving the imgAreaSelect selector around a bit.

Comment: Yes @Hogan, and the answer is yes. I fill those two fields with jQuery within $(document).ready. It's a bit complex but there's another plugin called one-click upload or ocupload which handles the uploading of the image in the first place.  It has a "onComplete" option/event, and it's in _there_ where I set these two fields using jQuery: $(#current_height).val('current_height_value_from_ajax_request');  I'm now throwing a console.log during that event, and can confirm it's only hitting that event once.

Comment: @smd2008 - and you are not changing those values in the onSelectChange event?

Comment: nope. onSelectChange just calls preview, and preview just reads those values. Since they don't change after the initial image upload, maybe I need to just look at moving that out of preview so they're only read once. That would probably solve it, but I'd love to figure out what's actually causing the problem.  :)

Answer (score 0):

This problem was caused by the [Firebug Lite extension for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bmagokdooijbeehmkpknfglimnifench). The problem occurred whether the Firebug Lite panel was open or not, and whether I was logging output to the console or not.  Now I know to test things in Incognito. I appreciate everyone's time and apologize for the false alarm...